# force push current

Tags: amperage

Is it possible to push a certain amount of current into a load?

For example I want to make a circuit that charges a battery from an unstable incoming power (windmill) and I want it to push all the incoming power into a battery no matter how small or big the incoming power is... the max incoming power is 330watts and battery is 12v so the current would not get higher than 30amps, how can I always get whatever current I get pushed fully into the battery? Ohms law is pretty clear so I don't know if it is even possible.. the resistance should be extremely low which could create a short circuit

Comment: You would want a regulator, and then assume if the voltage is properly regulating, then voltage is fixed. Then it's just a matter of the Power equation, P = IV. Power produced by the windmill gets injected into the end device in the form of current, assuming the voltage is high enough to maintain the regulated current

Comment: Ohm's law means that if your load is too resistive, you will NEVER be able to push more current through it than the maximum based on resistance though

Comment: This is a load matching problem. You need to think about it in two steps. The first one is that you need to maintain the optimal input voltage (or current) so that you get the maximum amount of power from your windmill. The second step is that you need to keep the output voltage equal to the battery voltage by adjusting the output current. So you need a DC-DC converter between the windmill and battery that can somehow do that.

Comment: It's there a way to ask for as much amps as possible and redirect that to the battery? Say a circuit regulating the Voltage and another that demands 50A, If the windmill is generating 330w then the demand will get around 30A and you push that into the regulated stream which pushes towards the battery?

Comment: How can I know the battery's resistance? Can you use a multimeter to check it? A battery emits power so I don't know if it is possible and heard that you can't measure a resistance if there is power.. and frankly I am too afraid of burning my multimeter... I can't afford another one!

Answer (score 1):

It's not really Ohm's law you're looking at.

And it's also not really just the current.

You mean: I want all the power, regardless if it's a miliwatt or a kilowatt (even though it's never a kilowatt) to go into the battery. Irrespective of voltage and/or current. "Forcing a current" is easy, just have your power-source force the current, and it will go, until your battery says BANG! and the surroundings are covered in Lead-shrapnel and battery acid.

So you need something that makes voltage from W to X with current Y to Z into charging a battery.

That's possible, you are looking for the term "DC-DC converter" if it's DC voltage, or "AC-DC converter" if it's AC voltage. Or you can rectify the AC voltage yourself, smooth it a little and then put that into the DC-DC converter.

If you don't want to do the battery charge management yourself you're also looking at a "Charge Controller", "Battery Management System" (BMS) or "Power Control Mechanism" -- I'm guessing that one, I only know the acronym:-- (PCM).

What type you need for those, that's all down to your EXACT devices, rather than just a conceptual idea.

If the voltage from the generator is a bit lower than the battery voltage to somewhat higher than the battery voltage, say from 7V to 30V, you can use a DC-DC "SEPIC Converter". Efficiency for a good one can go into the 90%'s, for a "cheaper" one it'll be 70% to 80% most likely.

If the incoming voltage goes from 3V to 300V, you'll have a tough task. It's no easy feat finding an (even remotely) efficient "SEPIC" converter for such a wide voltage range.

If the voltage is at least a few volts above the battery voltage up to mid-voltage, about 50V, you can use a reasonably normal DC-DC Buck converter. Again, if it goes from 16V to 300V, not going to be easy.

If the voltage is near switching PSU levels; 90VAC (or 120VDC) to 260VAC (or 360VDC) you can use... a switching PSU. MeanWell is an acceptable cheap brand, works with the voltages stated and on Mouser a 350W one might cost in the $70 range, I would expect.

But also consider: If the voltage during normal operation goes up to 300V, will there be any useful power to be had from anything below 90V with your generator? (useful being more than a few percent of average). If no: Then just use something from 90V to 350V and protect it from voltages 360V and up (if that can happen, even unlikely but possibly: that's good for a whole other question once you've made all your other choices).

Which output voltage you need (12V? 14V? 15v? 18V?) depends on the Battery ("12V" = Car battery? Traction battery? LiFePO4 battery?) and Battery Management circuit you end up building or buying, so I'm not going to touch that until you figure out more of your specifics.

You're welcome to ask another question once you're there, don't forget to link to this question for back story when you do. Someone (not necessarily me) will probably give you a decent answer to the next couple of questions once you've done some 'looking up of stuff'.

Comment: I don't want to but.. it's pointless if I do since this is for learning purpose.. I just want the circuit to require as much amps as possible from the source... as I know it, the amperage that goes through the circuit and into the load are the circuits and load's demand.. I want it to force push 30amps regardless of the loss whether it is 1ohm or 10k ohm, some sort of an ampere regulator, is that possible? If not what if I have a certain load and want add high amps to go into it as possible?

Comment: @bakriawad In the hour of the day of my answer I forgot to consider the loading resistance requirement of a harvesting situation. You need something that draws the maximum amount of power on the windmill side and creates the battery charging voltage from that, that much is valid in my answer. But that cannot always be 30A, since your windmill isn't always running full power. You mustn't keep thinking of "it'll always be 30A", you must find a system that creates the right situation for your battery, if the windmill makes 11V to 15V, it'll be a DC/DC system with optimum windmill loading input.

Comment: @bakriawad If you want to create a DC/DC regulator that always _TRIES_ to make 30A from the incoming signal, that's perfectly possible, but if the input is 30W, you will always only get 0.95V as maximum. No machine in the world will magicaly add power for you, or all us engineers would be swimming in free energy.

Comment: I am fully aware of that, I don't want it to always push 30A, just push as much ampere as it can Get from the source... (maybe with a max of 50A) in relation to the 12V regulation.. so it is ok to drop to 0.5A at 12V if the source is putting in 6w.. but at 330w I want it to push the max power it is getting this 30A.. I am aware of some high amps chargers but those depend on constant and stable and bigger power, where here it varies... so how can I make sure that it will almost always push full power into the load?

Comment: @bakriawad As I say in my answer: If the input voltage is below and above of the battery voltage, but not by huge margins (8V to 30V limits) you need a SEPIC DC/DC converter. Stop referring to the current for the power conversion and only start worrying about that when you do battery management (which you will want to do). In 'China' SEPIC is also simply known as "Boost-Buck Converter". But pre-bought stuff isn't going to get you the maximum power point as EM-Fields refers to.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum power out of your windmill is 300 watts, but that's into a particular load resistance.

If, for example, your load was an infinite impedance, (an open) the windmill's voltage would rise to its maximum commensurate with that windspeed, but it would put no current into the load, hence the load would dissipate no power.

Conversely, if the load was a short, the windmill would put whatever current it could through the short but, again, dissipate no power in the load.

However, at some load resistance between an open and a short, and with the windmill going balls-to-the-wall, it would put 300 watts into the load.

If your load was a battery, then the current the windmill could force through it would be the windmill's output voltage minus the battery voltage, divided by the circuit resistance, and the power into the battery would be the current through the battery times the voltage across it.

Comment: For every wind speed, there is a maximum power available from the windmill. But you will only get that maximum if you present the right load voltage or current. This is similar to MPPT in a solar panel with the added complication that the rotational speed of the windmill takes a lot longer to respond to load changes than a solar panel does.

Comment: @mkeith: Not the right load voltage or current, the right load **resistance**.

Comment: Well, it has to have the correct V-I relationship. I hesitate to call it a resistance if it is actually a DC-DC converter. It is not wrong in this case to say it has to have the right voltage or current. There will be a unique current that results in maximum power extraction. Or a unique voltage if you prefer to look at it that way. If you knew what it was ahead of time, you could just regulate to it. The resistance you are talking about is the unique voltage divided by the unique current.

Comment: The voltage will always be between 11V and 15V, so I am not sure how I can get the amperage to be at its max possible... it is not going to be 1 battery so watching out for the batteries life is not a problem